# How to export settings from NoSQL Manager for another computer?

Tags: nosql-manager

I would like to export my server settings in [NoSQL Manager](http://www.mongodbmanager.com/) from one computer, then import those settings to another computer.  How do I do this?

Comment: Look for your `mongo.config` file and copy that.

Comment: @DavidPostill I am not trying to export my MongoDB config.  I am trying to export my **NoSQL Manager** connection settings.

Comment: Then [edit] your title and question to say so. It is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NoSQL Manager for MongoDB stores all settings in appConfig.xml file.

Usually this file is located here

```
C:\ProgramData\NoSQL Manager Group\NoSQL Manager for MongoDB\appConfig.xml
```

or here

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\NoSQL Manager Group\NoSQL Manager for MongoDB\appConfig.xml
```

Find this file on your old computer and copy it into the new one (please note: the tool should be closed and restarted to use the newly placed config file).

UPD: The export\import settings feature has been added in the version 5.4.

Comment: Thanks!  I've been looking for this info for years.  I suppose I could have searched these places....